# trust region: conjugacy in dogleg method?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm reading Nocedal & Wright's text in conjunction with a reference on the Conjugate Gradient method, and I'm wondering if there is any connection between the two. Is the second step $p^B$ conjugate in any sense to the first (steepest descent) step $p^U$?

[image]